# Section in hebrew letters

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, hebrew

I have a document in english with few sentences in hebrew.

At one place I had like to make the Section title in hebrew however it appears at the left side of the paper instead of the right side.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{culmus}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}


\begin{document} 
.
.
.
\newpage
\begin{flushright}
\section{משוואות}
\end{flushright}
```

[image]
I tried the above however is also did not work.

Also, the text seems to be in different text compared to section in english:

[image]
Thank you

EDIT:

The following solved to horizontal alignment:

```
\R{\section{משוואות}}
```

Comment: I don't have suitable fonts to test, but maybe you could try to wrap the whole section in `\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew} 

\section{משוואות}
משוואות
\end{otherlanguage}`

Comment: Also if your document is mainly in English, you should load `\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}` (the primary language last)